# How to have streaming plotly histograms in R?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, dashboard

Streaming graphs (aka realtime charts) are quite easy to use in plotly, as shown in this tutoriel

https://plot.ly/r/streaming/#streaming-in-r

This article however only deals with scatter plot, and I wondered, whether a streaming graph may be doable for an histogram.

I adapted the given example but could not make it work. Here is a reproducible Shiny code, just copy it into an app.R file and run it in Rstudio:

app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

rand <- function() {
  runif(1, min=1, max=9)
}

ui <- fluidPage(

  headerPanel(h1("Streaming in Plotly", align = "center")),
  br(),
  div(actionButton("button", "Extend Trace"), align = "center"),
  br(),
  div(plotlyOutput("plot2"), id='graph')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  p2 <- plot_ly(
    x = rnorm(n=1),
    type = 'histogram')%>%
    layout(
      xaxis = list(range = c(-10,10)),
      yaxis = list(range = c(0,10))
    )
  ##
  ## Output to UI
  output$plot2 <- renderPlotly(p2)
  ##
  ## Update once button clicked
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    data <- rnorm(n=1000)
    #while(TRUE){
    for( i in 1:1000 ){
      val <- data[i]
      Sys.sleep(0.1)
      plotlyProxy("plot2", session) %>%
        plotlyProxyInvoke("extendTraces", list(y=list(list(val))), list(0))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Well, the `for` or `while` loops will block the thread so wont be able to do anything till it finishes. That example from `https://plot.ly/r/streaming/#streaming-in-r` a bit misleading and shouldn't have been put up there as it blocks any access to the app by others

Comment: Right, how would you make the process on-going? Using invalidLater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change `x` values in `plotlyProxyInvoke` not `y`:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

rand <- function() {
  runif(1, min=1, max=9)
}

ui <- fluidPage(

  headerPanel(h1("Streaming in Plotly", align = "center")),
  br(),
  div(actionButton("button", "Extend Trace"), align = "center"),
  br(),
  div(plotlyOutput("plot2"), id='graph')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  p2 <- plot_ly(
    x = rnorm(n=1),
    type = 'histogram')%>%
    layout(
      xaxis = list(range = c(-10,10)),
      yaxis = list(range = c(0,10))
    )
  ##
  ## Output to UI
  output$plot2 <- renderPlotly(p2)
  ##
  ## Update once button clicked
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    data <- rnorm(n=1000)
    #while(TRUE){
    for( i in 1:1000 ){
      val <- data[i]
      Sys.sleep(0.1)
      plotlyProxy("plot2", session) %>%
        plotlyProxyInvoke("extendTraces", list(x=list(list(val))), list(0))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```